# Webhdfs returns wrong datanode address

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-plugins, webhdfs

```
curl -i -X PUT "http://SomeHostname:50070/webhdfs/v1/file1?op=CREATE"
HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Location: http://sslave0:50075/webhdfs/v1/file1?op=CREATE&overwrite=false
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
```

here it return sslave0 for datanode, seem like an internal address to me

Answer (score 0):

With WebHDFS, the NameNode web interface @port 50070 in your case accepts the put request and assigns the metadata information about the file to be stored. It then returns a redirect to a Data Node address (the ssalve0:50075 address) where the actual Http PUT is completed.

Bottom line - the Name Node doesn't store any real data, only metadata. It's the Data Nodes which store the actual information for a file - hence the redirect

If you want to have a single proxy node by which you don't have to deal with the data nodes in this way, then you want to configure [HttpFs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/index.html) instead.

Comment: is there anyway for namenode to return datanode external ip instead?

Comment: Not without stopping all your datanodes and reconfiguring their /etc/hosts file (which will have downsides as all HDFS traffic will flow over the external IPs too). You could also have the internal hostnames added to a DNS server, or add the mappings into your client machines /etc/hosts file. You can read more about how the data nodes discover and report their addresses to the namenode in the book **Hadoop Operations** by Eric Sammer, Page 57