# Access WebHDFS on Hortonworks Hadoop (AWS EC2)

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm facing an issue with the WebHDFS access on my Amazon EC2 machine. I have installed Hortonworks HDP 2.3 btw.

I can retrieve the file status from my local machine in the browser (chrome) with following http request:

```
http://<serverip>:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/admin/file.csv?op=GETFILESTATUS
```

This works fine but if I try to open the file with `?op=OPEN`, then it redirects me to the private DNS of the machine, which I cannot access:

```
http://<privatedns>:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/admin/file.csv?op=OPEN&namenoderpcaddress=<privatedns>:8020&offset=0
```

I also tried to get access to WebHDFS from the AWS machine itself with this command:

```
[ec2-user@<ip> conf]$ curl -i http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/admin/file.csv?op=GETFILESTATUS
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Does anyone know why I cannot connect to localhost or why the OPEN on my local machine does not work?
Unfortunately I couldn't find any tutorial to configure the WebHDFS for a Amazon machine.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936313/webhdfs-returns-wrong-datanode-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the namenode redirects you to the datanode. Seems like you installed a single-node cluster, but conceptually the namenode and datanode(s) are distinct, and in your configuration the datanode(s) live/listen on the private side of your EC2 VPC.

You could reconfigure your cluster to host the datanodes on the public IP/DNS (see [HDFS Support for Multihomed Networks](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsMultihoming.html)), but I would not go that way. I think the proper solution is to add a [Know gateway](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_Knox_Gateway_Admin_Guide/content/ch01.html), which is a specialized component for accessing a private cluster from a public API. Specifically, you will have to configure the datanode URLs, see [Chapter 5. Mapping the Internal Nodes to External URLs](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_Knox_Gateway_Admin_Guide/content/ch05.html). The example there seems spot on for your case:

> For example, when uploading a file with WebHDFS service:
>
> - The external client sends a request to the gateway WebHDFS service.
> - The gateway proxies the request to WebHDFS using the service URL.
> - WebHDFS determines which DataNodes to create the file on and returns
>     the path for the upload as a Location header in a HTTP redirect, which
>     contains the datanode host information.
> - The gateway augments the routing policy based on the datanode hostname
>     in the redirect by mapping it to the externally resolvable hostname.
> - The external client continues to upload the file through the gateway.
> - The gateway proxies the request to the datanode by using the augmented
>     routing policy.
> - The datanode returns the status of the upload and the gateway again
>     translates the information without exposing any internal cluster
>     details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right in your assumption that I have installed a single node cluster. I think I will try to setup the Knox Gateway. I let you know if this solved the problem

Comment: I tried to solve my problem with WebHDFS and the knox gateway, but I could not start the ldap-demo-server so I tried to use HTTPfs and this works fine. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer!